# how to restrict image to show insider border

Tags: android, android-layout

my screen not show image fit on border is goes out of border seeimage  https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZBdh.jpg   is show tomoattow and cheexz image out of frame help me how do i fixed it?? i want to show first two images inside border like third image bread which correctly show inside border

```
    holder.txtText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title2);
    holder.imgThumb = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image2);

    holder.txtText.setText(fifthscreen.Category_name.get(position));
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(fifthscreen.Category_image.get(position),
            activity, holder.imgThumb);


   <com.schoollunchapp.HorizontalListView
           android:id="@+id/listview2"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="150dp"
             android:layout_below="@+id/test_button_text5"

           android:background="#ffffff"/>


       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

     <LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"

   >

    <ImageView
android:id="@+id/image2"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
 android:layout_height="100dp"
 android:scaleType="centerCrop"

 android:paddingRight="5dp"
 android:paddingLeft="5dp"
 android:paddingTop="10dp"
 android:paddingBottom="10dp"
   android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
   android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
   android:background="@drawable/imagebgborder"
android:src="@drawable/icon"
/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/title2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="#000"
   android:padding="15dp"
   android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
/>



   </LinearLayout>


  <!--imageborder.xml--->


                     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000" />
<padding android:left="2dp" android:top="2dp" android:right="2dp" 
  android:bottom="2dp"  
 />


 <corners android:bottomRightRadius="10dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"

android:topLeftRadius="10dp" android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: check my imageview code is correctly ????

Comment: Is your `imagebgborder` a 9 patch image??

Comment: no is xml file i ithink mistake is in image padding or imagelayoutmargin left or write

Comment: @user2686011 I think do not. Could you show the imagebgborder file?

Comment: i paste it check above my code i edit my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code

```
  <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageview1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
```

Then follow below points:

1. Set your image to Imageview as 'src' and not as 'background'.
2. Crop your image width and height related to your Frame height and width.

Comment: i set image as imagesrc   imagebackground is just a border around imageview

Comment: I am saying remove  android:scaleType="centerCrop" from your Imageview and add android:adjustViewBounds="true" to your imageview and declare width and height as wrapcontent instead of 90 and 100 dip.

Comment: No problem you can set background also.

Comment: im using horizontal listview so cant declair width height wrap content

Comment: Use RelativeLayout as parent layout for Imageview. Declare your Imageview background to RelativeLayout and remove backgorund fro Imageview.

Comment: i just replace scaletype with   android:adjustViewBounds="true"  is work now